# RotationVector Sensor ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: android, android-sensors

i was coding an app which get all information about sensors. I have a problem on the rotation vector one. I saw on the official android website that you have 4 values to get for this sensor :

TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR :

> SensorEvent.values[0]     Rotation vector component along the x axis (x *
>   sin(θ/2)).
>
> SensorEvent.values[1]     Rotation vector component along the y axis (y *
>   sin(θ/2)).
>
> SensorEvent.values[2]     Rotation vector component along the z axis (z *
>   sin(θ/2)).
>
> SensorEvent.values[3]     Scalar component of the rotation vector
>   ((cos(θ/2)).1

Here's my code :

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Get sensors values
    float x, y, z, s;
    String s1 = "stringX", s2 = "stringY", s3 = "stringZ", s4 = "stringS";

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {


            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2];
            s = event.values[3]; // <============== The error indicate this line

            s1 = "" + x;
            s2 = "" + y;           
            s3 = "" + z;
            s4 = "" + s;

            tvx.setText(s1);
            tvy.setText(s2);
            tvz.setText(s3);
            tvs.setText(s4);

    }
}
```

here's the log cat :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
at com.example.sensortnewtest.RotationVectorInfos.onSensorChanged(RotationVectorInfos.java:128)
at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does it mean that event.values[3] is not possible?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Android documentation on SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html), the fourth value (i.e. event.values[3]) is optional, and is only present when values.length = 4.  (Search for TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR on that web-page).  So you're simply encountering the case where it's not provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is 3 D way .There is rotation in x, y and z axis only  What is meaning of S here. Please do not use this. I hope you understand